# Create a percentage in CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, percentage

How can I print percentage in CNN if the case is I want to predict something like "how well the training data match the test data" with percentage appearing in the output.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean percentage of predicted labels matching the actual labels, in training or testing a Convolutional Neural Network? Because "how well the training data match the test data" does not seem to make sense. Training data and test data are not supposed to be the same, or even have any overlap. The given data-set is divided in to 2 parts: training set (e.g. 70 %) and test set (e.g. 30 %).

Depending on the deep learning platform you are using (e.g. TensorFlow or PyTorch), you may be able to display the accuracy (percentage of predicted labels that match the actual labels) in every epoch of training, and also for testing. Try checking sample code on https://www.tensorflow.org/ or https://pytorch.org/.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i see. I'll try your references later.

Thanks btw 